# Command Line Argument c#

Tags: c#

I have a standalone example program which when executed gives a terminal to get the input as "0" and then shows another window which is essentially the camera function.

[image]
[image]

program for camera which intakes the command line arguments:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using mv.impact.acquire;


#if USE_DISPLAY
    using mv.impact.acquire.display;
#endif // #if USE_DISPLAY
using mv.impact.acquire.examples.helper;

namespace SW_FormsApplication3
{
    class ContinousCapture
    {

        public static void StartCamera(string[] args)
        {

          //Acquire camera image and display it on window

        }//End Method
    }//End class
}//End namespace
```

My toolstrip button to invoke the method:

```
private void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ContinousCapture.StartCamera();

    }
```

I want to implement the same in my application but in my case, I should click a button on the form (toolstrip button) so that I can have the image window show up. How can I achieve this, meaning how to invoke a method that takes in command line args ?

I have already tried,  `ContinousCapture.StartCamera(null)`; I have resolved the problem with PDB file but not able to figure out why the console doesnt show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple as that `ContinousCapture.StartCamera(null);`